# Lost my computer and external hard drive with my keystone file

Tags: wallets, keystore

Last week my laptop bag was stole. It contained my laptop with my ethereum wallet and my external hard drive where i backed up my keystore file.  I'm fairly new to ethereum, I purchased 1 eth back in October and have been watching the price rise. I'm assuming I've lost it all but if anybody has any suggestions i'd love to hear them.

Thanks,
Curtis

Answer (score 1):

There's likely nothing you can do besides report the theft and try to get it back. The takeaway is that backups serve very little purpose if kept in the same bag.

Comment: Lesson learned!